# Concatenate Column Strings based on an Integer

Tags: r

I want to create strings as shown below by date first elected, for example.

df:

```
Name         Party       FirstElected
Bob         Liberal      1985
Joe         Republican   1985
Sarah        Green       1980
Bill       Libertarian   1980
Tom       Conservative   1987
```

Goal:

```
Year            PeopleElected
1985   "Bob (Liberal); Joe (Republican)"
1980   "Sarah (Green); Bill (Libertarian)"
1987   "Tom (Conservative)"
```

I assume some combination of `paste` and `apply/aggregate` can do this...but I haven't had much luck so far.

Comment: Think no need for regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste/sprintf` to create the format grouped by 'FirstElected'.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'FirstElected', we wrap the 'Party' with parentheses, concatenate with 'Name' using `sprintf`, then use `paste`, with `collapse='; '` to create a single string.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(PeopleElected=paste(sprintf('%s (%s)',
                Name, Party), collapse="; ")) , by = FirstElected]
#   FirstElected                     PeopleElected
#1:         1985   Bob (Liberal); Joe (Republican)
#2:         1980 Sarah (Green); Bill (Libertarian)
#3:         1987                Tom (Conservative)
```

Or using a single `paste`

```
setDT(df1)[, list(PeopleElected=paste(Name, ' (', Party, ')',
           sep='', collapse='; ')) , by=FirstElected]
```

Comment: helpful and educational as always, akrun. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

And a `dplyr` approach (because I don't speak `data.table` yet)

```
df1 <- data.frame(Name = c("Bob", "Joe", "Sarah", "Bill", "Tom"),
                  Party = c("Liberal", "Republican", "Green", "Libertarian",
                            "Conservative"),
                  FirstElected = c(1985, 1985, 1980, 1980, 1987))

df1 %>% 
  group_by(FirstElected) %>%
  summarise(PeopleElected = paste0(paste0(Name, " (", Party, ")"), 
                                   collapse = "; "))

Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  FirstElected                     PeopleElected
         (dbl)                             (chr)
1         1980 Sarah (Green); Bill (Libertarian)
2         1985   Bob (Liberal); Joe (Republican)
3         1987                Tom (Conservative)
```